# How can I solve a JNI Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: when running a java program with docker openjdk:8?

Tags: java, docker, noclassdeffounderror

How can I solve a JNI Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j/TwitterException when running a java program with docker openjdk:8

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD dist/TwitterData.jar TwitterData.jar  
ENV CLASSPATH .:.twitter4j.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","TwitterData.jar"]
```

Error Shown:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j/TwitterException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: twitter4j.TwitterException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: You coppied the main binary, but did you copy the `twitter4j` dependency?

Comment: When I built the project to get the jar, I added the dependency and the build the jar. Should I use the copy command in the dockerfile?

Comment: From the NoClassDef error, it would seem as if `twitter4j` was not copied into your export. How did you build `TwitterData.jar`? Either try messing with the build and validating that the dependencies are actually exported, or yes, copy your dependencies explicitly.

Comment: I used an IDE (Netbeans) to build it. I added the dependencies from the project properties options and then made sure to click on to the option of compress jar file. I added `COPY dist/lib/twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar  twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar` to the dockerfile but got the same error.

Comment: When copying explicitely, make sure the CLASSPATH is also correct., in this case it should reference the file by the whole name, as `twitter4j.jar` != `twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar`

Comment: I already changed the dockerfile with the correct names:
`FROM openjdk:8
ADD dist/TwitterData.jar TwitterData.jar
COPY dist/lib/twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar  twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar
ENV CLASSPATH .:.dist/lib/twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","TwitterData.jar"]`

But I am still getting the same error:  **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j/TwitterException**

Comment: The Dockerfile `COPY` command is the the form of `COPY <src> <dst>`, so here, your classpath should not include `dist/lib`, as you are copying directly into the project root.

Comment: You could also try removing the ENV CLASSPATH line, and add the classpath directly in the java launch command. `ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-cp", "/path/to/twitter4j.jar", "-jar", "TwitterData.jar"]`

Comment: Thank you very much. I corrected the dockerfile once more and changed the copy command. When I build the docker, I dont get any errors but when I try to run it, then I get the error **NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j/TwitterException**

Comment: I also removed the ENV CLASSPATH line and added it directly from the Entrypoint but it is still not working. Any ideas on why could this be happening?

Answer (score -1):

In order to solve this error, I got into the image's shell and added the PATH variables manually, It works fine after that.